# Efficient implementation of summed area table/integral image in R

Tags: r, loops, image-processing, runtime, integral

I am trying to construct a [summed area table or integral image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table) given an image matrix. For those of you who dont know what it is, from wikipedia:

> A summed area table (also known as an integral image) is a data structure and algorithm for quickly and efficiently generating the sum of values in a rectangular subset of a grid

In other words, its used to sum up values of any rectangular region in the image/matrix in constant time.

I am trying to implement this in R. However, my code seems to take too long to run.

Here is the pseudo code from [this link](http://people.scs.carleton.ca/~roth/iit-publications-iti/docs/gerh-50002.pdf). `in` is the input matrix or image and `intImg` is whats returned

```
for i=0 to w do
   sum←0

   for j=0 to h do
      sum ← sum + in[i, j]

      if i = 0 then
         intImg[i, j] ← sum
      else
         intImg[i, j] ← intImg[i − 1, j] + sum
      end if
   end for 
end for
```

And here is my implementation

```
w = ncol(im)
h = nrow(im)
intImg = c(NA)
length(intImg) = w*h

for(i in 1:w){ #x
  sum = 0;
  for(j in 1:h){ #y
    ind = ((j-1)*w)+ (i-1) + 1 #index
    sum = sum + im[ind]
    if(i == 1){
      intImg[ind] = sum
    }else{
      intImg[ind] = intImg[ind-1]+sum
    }
  }
}
intImg = matrix(intImg, h, w, byrow=T)
```

Example of input and output matrix:

[image]

However, on a `480x640` matrix, this takes ~ 4 seconds. In the paper they describe it to take on the order of milliseconds for those dimensions.

Am I doing something inefficient in my loops or indexing?

I considered writing it in C++ and wrapping it in R, but I am not very familiar with C++.

Thank you

Comment: a link to `im` would make this reproducible. it's hard for me to parse what you're doing without an example, but you can probably use `colSums()` and `rowSums()` or some other vectorized function(s).

Comment: `im` is just any matrix. I've added an example of the input and output in the question

Comment: How much improvement do you get by changing `intImg = c(NA)` to `intImg <- rep(NA, 480*460)`?

Comment: Hi joran, I've tried that. Doesn't change much. What's the difference?

Comment: You need to start being much more specific. "Doesn't change much" and providing images of example matrices isn't very helpful.

Comment: @by0 - it relates to how R has to (re)allocate memory for every iteration of a loop.

Comment: Doesn't change much, meaning its still around 4 seconds. 4.02 seconds to be exact. Here, you can just copy paste this in your R console for an example matrix that isn't an image: `m = matrix(c(4,1,2,2,0,4,1,3,3,1,0,4,2,1,3,2), 4,4,byrow=T)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try to use `apply` (isn't faster than your for-loops if you pre-allocating the memory):

```
areaTable <- function(x) {
  return(apply(apply(x, 1, cumsum), 1, cumsum))
}

areaTable(m)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    4    5    7    9
# [2,]    4    9   12   17
# [3,]    7   13   16   25
# [4,]    9   16   22   33
```

Comment: It will be quicker - though probably not by a huge margin - as you are doing 8 `cumsum` calls (plus the loop forming code and allocation etc) whereas the OP's code is doing lots of calls to `+` to give the equivalent of your `cumsum` calls. As it is interpreted code all those function calls will add up.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I'm actually surprised at how much faster it is, based on a quick timing of a 500x500 example.

Comment: Yes, its vastly faster. I gave up waiting for two nested `for` loops, the double-apply took less than a second.

Comment: @joran I should have stuck to my initial thought - I went back and added the caveat before submitting the comment in a moment of self-doubt. `cumsum` is very efficient code and all those `+` calls will mount up as the dimensions of the input increase. Profiling the OP's code will show that.

Comment: @GavinSimpson: you are right, I didn't thought about this fact of interpreted code.

Comment: @sgibb, explain how can we make it fast in c++?